# Javascript function with dynamic/array ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, dynamic, color-picker

I have a question about a dynamic call of an JavaScript function. Here's my problem:

Let's say I have an element(div) which includes a colorpicker. I want to use/clone this element dynamically (how many times the user wants). Call for this colorpicker looks like:
the code can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/CJhqc/1/ (have put it in fiddle because it get's messed up here, not for testing there)

where the id is for example variable called `my_color`. I added `[]` to the input so that I can have more of this colorpicker items called. This is ok, I can have like 5 this elements and can read each of this inputs. The problem comes with the colorpicker call. The colopicker now has `id="color_picker"` which then calls:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#color_picker').children('div').css('backgroundColor', '<?php echo $value; ?>');    
    jQuery('#color_picker').ColorPicker({
        color: '<?php echo $value; ?>',
        onShow: function (colpkr) {
            jQuery(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
            return false;
        },
        onHide: function (colpkr) {
            jQuery(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
            return false;
        },
        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {    
            jQuery('#color_picker').children('div').css('backgroundColor', '#'+ hex);
            jQuery('#color_picker').next('input').attr('value','#'+ hex);
        }
    });
});
```

The problem: If I have now 3 of this items, the JavaScript for them is always the same. The input next to the colorpicker is "arrayed" -> `<?php echo $id; ?>[]` , but how do I set the colorpicker JavaScript for each of this items. And can't give the `color_picker id -> color_picker[]`. Now if I want to change color for the second item(for example) the color will be changing for the first one and not the second one. Guess each needs it's own JavaScript, but how to call it?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: class instead of id and call with `jQuery('.color_picker')` ?

Comment: Hi, if using this and having(for example 3 items). When changing color on one of them makes the same change for all(set color for item2 also sets the same color to item1 and item3). Any idea how to make just a change for the one I am really changing?

Comment: Reference it with `jQuery(this)` instead of `jQuery(.<classname>)` inside the `onChange` function

Comment: Hi, can you point out the code example how it would look like for the code posted above? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the class of the color picker (in the fiddle it already has `colorSelector` so I'll use that) instead of the id, and reference `jQuery(this)` inside the onChange handler to work with the right children and input. I think that should work like you want it to.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    //init all color pickers to the same $value
    jQuery('.colorSelector').children('div').css('backgroundColor', '<?php echo $value; ?>');    
    //init ColorPicker handling for all color pickers
    jQuery('.colorSelector').ColorPicker({
        color: '<?php echo $value; ?>',
        onShow: function (colpkr) {
            jQuery(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
            return false;
        },
        onHide: function (colpkr) {
            jQuery(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
            return false;
        },
        //handle onChange individually
        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {    
            jQuery(this).children('div').css('backgroundColor', '#'+ hex);
            jQuery(this).next('input').attr('value','#'+ hex);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi tnx for this, I have tried i many ways but still it doesn't work for me. Any other suggestion?